# Equivalence of norms in a finite dimensional $K$-vector space, $K$ being a valued field

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am interested in the generalization of the well-known theorem of norm equivalences for finite dimensional spaces over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. However, I have trouble understanding the proof I found in a lecture notes.

We fix $K$ a valued field whose norm is denoted by $|\cdot|$. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $K$-vector space. We shall prove that all norms over $V$ are equivalent. For this, we use induction on $d=\dim(V)$.  We fix a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_d$ of $V$ and we consider the sup norm $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ with respect to it. We also fix a norm $||\cdot||$ on $V$. It is enough to prove that $||\cdot||$ is equivalent to $||\cdot||_{\infty}$.

The result is clear when $d=1$, given that $||\cdot||$ is "$K$-linear" with respect to the valuation $|\cdot|$ over $K$.

For the induction step, at first it is clear that $||\cdot|| \leq C||\cdot||_{\infty}$ where $C=\sup(||e_i||)$. As for the reverse inequality, assume towards a contradiction that there does not exist any $D>0$ such that $||\cdot||_{\infty} \leq D||\cdot||$. The lecture notes I use now state the following:

> There exists a sequence of vectors $u_n$ such that $||u_n||_{\infty} \geq 1$ for every $n$ and $||u_n||\rightarrow 0$.

I can't see how to build such a sequence $(u_n)$.

Considering the statement with $D=n$, I can build a sequence of vectors $v_n\in V$ such that $$||v_n||_{\infty} > n||v_n||$$

Now, if the base field were $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ as in the usual theorem, I could define $u_n := \frac{v_n}{||v_n||_{\infty}}$ and it would work. But because the base field may not contain the element $||v_n||_{\infty}\in \mathbb R$, this reasoning won't do here.

Would you have an idea as to how to construct a suitable sequence $(u_n)$ ?

NB: once such a sequence is constructed, it is not so difficult to conclude the proof using the induction hypothesis. I omit it here.

Comment: Existence of sequence $\|u_n\|_1\ge 1,\|u_n\|_2\to 0$ is the contradiction of $\|.\|_1 \le  C\|.\|_2$

Comment: @reuns The negation of "there exists $C>0$ such that $||\cdot||_1 \leq C||\cdot||_2$ is "for every $C>0$, there is a vector $v$ such that $||v||_1 > C||v||_2$. Applying this with any increasing sequence $(C_n)$ that goes to infinity (eg. $C_n=n$) should give relevant information, it leads to the sequence $(v_n)$ I defined. But I really do not see how to derive a suitable sequence $(u_n)$ from here.

Comment: Fix some $a\in K, |a|> 1$ and for each $n$ take $k$ such that  $\|v_n a^{k}\|_\infty\in [1,|a|)$ it works because both norms are assumed to  be $|.|$ linear

Comment: @reuns That is right, I just realized it at the moment you posted your comment. It works this way! Thank you very much for your hint. =) 

Besides, by definition of $||v||_{\infty}$, there always is an element $a\in K$ such that $|a| = ||v||_{\infty}$, namely the coordinate of $v$ which realize the maximum. I can divide each $v_n$ by the corresponding $a_n$ in order to obtain a suitable sequence $u_n$. This is neat!